# Error calling startActivityForResult on 3rd party SDK intent

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, android-gradle-plugin, nativescript

I am creating a NativeScript app. I have a .jar file that i'm pulling into my app via Gradle. I can interact with the .jar's classes/objects fine. However when I try to use an intent with startActivityForResult I get an error:

`Error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.xyz.payment.REQUEST (has extras) }`

My code:

```
let paymentRequest = new com.xyz.payment.PaymentRequest(new java.math.BigDecimal("50.00"));

app.android.onActivityResult = function (requestCode, resultCode, data) {
    console.log('onActivityResult');
};

let act = app.android.foregroundActivity || app.android.startActivity;

act.startActivityForResult(paymentRequest.createIntent(), 0);

// also tried
// app.android.currentContext.startActivityForResult(paymentRequest.createIntent(), 0);
```

I also added this to my manifest file:

`<activity android:name="com.xyz.payment.REQUEST"/>`

Edit. Added stack trace:

```
JS: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.xyz.payment.REQUEST (has extras) }
JS:     android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1809)
JS:     android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
JS:     android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4223)
JS:     android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4182)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:861)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:726)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:712)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:693)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:683)
JS:     com.tns.gen.android.widget.AdapterView_OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView_OnItemClickListener.java:14)
JS:     android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
JS:     android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1155)
JS:     android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3096)
JS:     android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4011)
JS:     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
JS:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
JS:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
JS:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6044)
JS:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
JS:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
JS:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
JS: ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
JS: Error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.aevi.payment.REQUEST (has extras) }
JS:     android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1809)
JS:     android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
JS:     android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4223)
JS:     android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4182)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:861)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:726)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:712)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:693)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:683)
JS:     com.tns.gen.android.widget.AdapterView_OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView_OnItemClickListener.java:14)
JS:     android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
JS:     android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1155)
JS:     android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3096)
JS:     android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4011)
JS:     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
JS:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
JS:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
JS:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6044)
JS:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
JS:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
JS:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
JS:     at Error (native)
JS:     at AppComponent.onTap (/data/data/org.nativescript.androidtest/files/app/app.component.js:18:13)
JS:     at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent0._handle_itemTap_1_0 (AppComponent.template.js:83:28)
JS:     at Object.<anonymous> (/data/data/org.nativescript.androidtest/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:366:24)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/data/data/org.nativescript.androidtest/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:281:29)
JS:     at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (/data/data/org.nativescript.androidtest/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js:46:41)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/data/data/org.nativescript.androidtest/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:280:35)
JS:     at Zone.runGuarded (/data/data/org.nativescript.androidtest/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:188:48)
JS:     at Object.callback (/data/data/org.nativescript.androidtest/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:164:30)
JS:     at ListView.Observable.notify (/data/data/org.nativescript.androidtest/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js:155:23)
JS: ERROR CONTEXT:
JS: [object Object]
07-04 10:23:06.070 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
07-04 10:23:06.070 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:861)
07-04 10:23:06.070 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:726)
07-04 10:23:06.070 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:712)
07-04 10:23:06.070 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:693)
07-04 10:23:06.070 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:683)
07-04 10:23:06.071 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
07-04 10:23:06.071 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:861)
07-04 10:23:06.071 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:726)
07-04 10:23:06.071 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:712)
07-04 10:23:06.071 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:693)
07-04 10:23:06.071 10809 10809 W System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:683)
07-04 10:23:06.075 10809 10809 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
07-04 10:23:06.075 10809 10809 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:861)
07-04 10:23:06.075 10809 10809 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:726)
07-04 10:23:06.075 10809 10809 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:712)
07-04 10:23:06.076 10809 10809 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:693)
07-04 10:23:06.076 10809 10809 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:683)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. I had not installed a package onto the android emulator that this code relied on which is why it was complaining that it was missing the activity.